# SVN to Git Migration: Move a selected set of commits to a new repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-filter-branch, git-filter

I am trying to migrate a very old `svn` repository to `git` and to rearrange directory structure. Initially the `svn` repository structure was like this.

**Stage A**

```
application/
            .svn
            dev/
                dev1/
                dev2/               
            test/
                test1/
                test2/
            others/
                others1/
                others2/
```

Over some years, the structure changed to something like this.

**Stage B**

```
application/
            .svn
            dev1/
                dev/
                test/
                others/
            dev2/
                dev/
                test/
                others/
```

Contents of

- dev/dev1 is moved to dev1/dev
- test/test1 is moved to dev1/test
- others/others1 is moved to dev1/others

Same movement is done for dev2 directory as well.

Now I have moved the source code to `git` using `git svn clone`, maintaining all commit history. Currently the directory structure is like this.

**Stage C**

```
application/
            .git
            dev1/
                dev/
                test/
                others/
            dev2/
                dev/
                test/
                others/
```

Now I want to split this repository into two new repositories like this

**Stage D**

```
dev1/
    .git
    dev/
    test/
    others/


dev2/
    .git/
    dev/
    test/
    others/
```

I have tried `git filter-branch subdirectory-filter` like this.

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dev1 --prune-empty
```

which successfully created the directory structure I wanted, **maintaining all the commit history of dev1 upto the movement mentioned in `Stage B`**. All the commits before the movement mentioned in `Stage B` is lost.

What I want to achieve is to create directory structure mentioned in `Stage D`, maintaining all commit histories of all files which are present in `dev1` and `dev2`.

*Important* : Most of the files present in `dev1` and `dev2` are created even before the creation of `dev1` and `dev2` - those files are later moved to `dev1`/`dev2`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create 2 copies of the repository from **stage C** — `dev1` and `dev2`. Then remove the directory *dev2* from the repo `dev1` and remove the directory *dev1* from the repo `dev2`. Then in both repositories move all subdirectories one level up and remove directories *dev1* and *dev2*.

```
cp -a repo_c dev1
cp -a repo_c dev2

cd dev1
git rm -rf dev2
cd dev1
git mv * ..
cd ..
git rm -rf dev1
git commit -m "Restructure repository"
```

Repeat the same for `dev2` exchanging *dev2* and *dev1*.

Comment: There is an issue with this approach. Both repositories will hold the history of each other - `dev1` will hold full history of `dev2`, which is not required. I guess the unnecessary histories will increase the size of git repository. The main idea of splitting the repositories is to reduce its size.

Comment: Those 2 subdirectories have a common history. You want to preserve it so IMO the simplest way to preserve the common part is to preserve everything.